# Coding a space between a shortcode generated form on Wordpress Theme

Tags: html, spacing

On my site I have a form I'm trying to create large space between things like Phone and Alternate Phone, you'll know what I'm talking about if you see on the link www.furnomenalpets.com/new-client-app/

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label>
    Phone
    <span class="required">
            (required)
          </span>
  </label>
  [tel* tel-503 id:258 class:form-control placeholder "(123) 456-7890"]
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
  <label>
    Alternate Phone
  </label>
  [tel* tel-503 id:258 class:form-control placeholder "(123) 456-7890"]
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create margin space between your container divs.

In your `.col-md-2` class add this rule:

`margin-bottom: 25px;`

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/t9jk3z3s/

If there's a problem let me know in the comment section. Good luck!

**Update:**

Based on your comment below, to add spacing in the HTML directly, simply add `<br>` tags after the closing divs (`</div>`).

Each `<br>` gives you a new line of space.

**Update 2:**

Use inline styles.

`<div class="col-md-2" style="margin-bottom: 25px;">`

Comment: Im doing this through a wordpress theme and I'm not sure where to got to add this in. Is there a way to add that rule just using HTML because I don't have a CSS tab on the Contact Form short code generator.

Comment: adding <br> brings it down to the next row, which is what I've been doing. However, I wanted to know if there's an HTML code for spacing it out horizontally.

Comment: you can do this within <style></style>

Comment: Are you able to use inline styles in the html tags?

Comment: Yeah, it moves them over horizontally, but it moves the one below it on the second row to the side rather than the one I wanted. 

I'll play around with this. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, play with the margin value until you find what works. Also check into other properties that may be affecting your div, such as `padding` and `line-height`.